# How do i fix my nodejs application using caddy as reverse proxy to render my css,javascipt files etc, which are located in the public directory

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, caddyfile

```
This my cadddyfile
my.domain.com{
     route /merchant* {
        reverse_proxy merchant:5000

    } 
    route /company* {
        reverse_proxy company:6500

    }
    route /dashboard* {
        reverse_proxy dashboard:8100

    }

    route / {
        reverse_proxy client:4500

    }

}
```

This my docker compose file
version: '3'

services:
dashboard:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.dashboard
container_name: dashboard
ports:
- "8100:8100"
env_file:
- .env

merchant:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.merchant
container_name: merchant
ports:
- "5000:5000"
env_file:
- .env

company:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.company
container_name: company
ports:
- "6500:6500"
env_file:
- .env

client:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile.index
container_name: index
ports:
- "4500:4500"
env_file:
- .env

caddy:
image: caddy/caddy:2.2.1-alpine
container_name: caddy-service
restart: unless-stopped
ports:
- "80:80"
- "443:443"
volumes:
- $PWD/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
- $PWD/site:/srv
- caddy_data:/data
- caddy_config:/config

volumes:
caddy_data:
caddy_config:

in my servers file the middleware is defined as  app.use(express.static('public))

i was exepecting when i render it in the browser the css and javascript will load but it only render the views files  but the css is not loading "  "